# Force localization app

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, localization

I'm actually developping an app which needs to force localization in his own settings (not with the general settings, I did not make the specifications, dont ask why I should do it :-))

I can force my app to use a specific Localizable.string file with this category :

```
+(NSString*)localizedString:(NSString*)string forLanguageCode:(NSString*)languageCode {

    NSString *pathToLocalizedBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:languageCode ofType:@"lproj"];

    if(!pathToLocalizedBundle) pathToLocalizedBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];
    NSBundle *aBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:pathToLocalizedBundle];
    return [aBundle localizedStringForKey:string value:@"" table:nil];
}
```

The problem I am facing is for localize some "Apple stuff", I mean like "edit" button or some default tab tab like these (featured and more) :

[image: Defaut tab bar]

I tried to change the `"AppleLanguages`" key in the `user default` but it works only if the app is restarted and I do not want it. Is this possible?

Comment: You need to reinitiate your view for instant change with `AppleLanguages` way.

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply, is there an easy way to reinitiate the view?

Comment: Add  localization Strings and  Change the language in your simulator or device settings .

Comment: Already done, I want to change the app language during the runtime, especially the system-localized strings such as edit button or back button

Answer (score -1):

You may want to have a visit here: http://aggressive-mediocrity.blogspot.in/2010/03/custom-localization-system-for-your.html

Comment: This link just shows how to use NSLocalizedString, my problem is to force the system to use a specific language for the system labels / button

Comment: The other methods would be hackish and you wouldn't want those. Even Apple doesn't recommend `AppleLanguages` trick.

Comment: But in case you really want to use it, try re-initiating the view by releasing and reallocating it again.

Comment: Weel, look like I can't directly do what I wanted, I will use the release / realloc method, thank you :-)